# How to spread rows with duplicate names easily?

Tags: r, tidyverse

How could I spread gear values using cyl as a key column?

#### Code

```
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, gear)%>%
  spread(cyl, gear)
```

#### Error

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (3, 8, 9, 18, 19, 20, 21, 26, 27, 28, 32), (1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 30), (5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29, 31)

#### Desired output

```
cyl gear
4 4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4
6 4,4,3,4,4,5
8 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5
```

Comment: Add row number like so `mtcars %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% select(...)`

Comment: I tried `mutate(rn = row_number())` as mentioned in the previous posts but didn't get what I wanted. @CPak

Comment: Does it work and the output is not what you want? Or does it throw an error? If the first, edit your post to describe why the output is not what you want and display desired output

Comment: As a guess - modify to `select(rn, cyl, gear)` and `spread(cyl, gear, fill=0)`

Comment: @CPak Nope, it doesn't work. I added the desired output as you suggested.

Comment: @Cpak, it doesn't work when I used the code as suggested before. Can you please untag "duplicate post".

Comment: Try like this: `mtcars %>% select(cyl,gear) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(gear = paste0(gear, collapse=","))`